# Changing text content when clicking on different icons

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm building a website for my business and I'm trying to create a section with three different icons representing different subdivisions.

I have text content below the icons and I would like it to change based on which icon is clicked. Similar section can be seen in [this website](http://randlesiddeley.co.uk/) (scroll down to the "services" part).

I'm a complete beginner and I'm using Wordpress with a multipurpose theme called Divi. I guess I could achieve similar results by using jQuery (?). Though, I wouldn't mind using a plugin if it makes the job easier.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure that are you able to do it by yourself like you said you are beginner, but I think that you can use this solution - but it will be needed some work. Also not sure that your website use bootstrap, is it use? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using **WordPress**, there's absolutely no need for you to deal with jQuery to have tabs.

An example of plugin you can use for those Tabs is [Tabby Responsive Tabs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabby-responsive-tabs/)

In any case, Tabs keyword is what you're looking for, and since you're saying that you are complete beginner, any free or premium Tabs plugin should do the job for you.

Comment: This is where you should start if you are a beginner, I got too excited!

Answer (score 1):

*edit => As your a beginner you should use a plugin like Bruno Kos suggested, although I will leave my answer up just in case someone else finds it useful*

I'm not sure on plugins but in the plain text editor you could try this (its relatively easy to get your head around):

```
//the Cartman image. Notice the onclick and how it launches the Cartman function below 
<img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i33463/xtudiando/south-park/Cartman.ico" onclick="cartman()">

//the kenny image. This one launches the Kenny function
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/xtudiando/south-park/128/Kenny-icon.png" onclick="kenny()">

//This is the p (paragraph) tag where we will inject our text 
<p id="text1"></p>


<script>

//This is some simple javascript. The first function is to inject the Kenny text between the <p></p> tags with the "id" "text1".
function kenny(){
document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Oh my god, you killed Kenny!";
}

//this function injects the Cartman text
function cartman(){
document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Screw you guys I'm going home";
}

</script>
```

example here http://js.do/code/131702 Go and have a fiddle! Use copy/paste and see if you can add another image and text

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on it: jQuery UI Library and one of the widget inside.

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

I think you'll be happy not just by having content inside JS code but toggling visibility of your post/page blocks. It will allows you to have editable easy content.

jQuery UI is popular but you can make it with no extra plugin at all.

As example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tabToggler').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $tabToggler = $(e.target);
    var $tabId = $tabToggler.data('id');

    $('.tab').hide();
    $('.tab[data-id="' + $tabId + '"]').show();
  })
});
```

```css
.tabToggler {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabToggler[data-id="1"]{
  background:red
}

.tabToggler[data-id="2"]{
  background:green
}

.tabToggler[data-id="3"]{
  background:blue
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tabToggler" data-id="1">First ICO</a>
<a href="#" class="tabToggler" data-id="2">Second ICO</a>
<a href="#" class="tabToggler" data-id="3">Third ICO</a>

<div class="tab" data-id="1">Content 1</div>
<div class="tab" data-id="2">Content 2</div>
<div class="tab" data-id="3">Content 3</div>
```

If you need some extra explanation I can update my answer with it.